# How get object from array in vuejs methods

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

In my data:

```
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      colaborador: [],
      colRestaurante: '',
    }
  }
```

in my created:

```
created() {
    this.consultarColaboradores() 
  },
```

in methods:

```
methods: {

async consultarColaboradores() {       
       ...
          if(userNameDoc.exists) {
            let userName = userNameDoc.data()

            let colaboradorDoc = await db.collection('usuarios')
                                    .doc(userName.uid)
                                    .collection('Colaboradores')
                                    .where("uidCol", '==', auth.currentUser.uid)
                                    .get()

                colaboradorDoc.docs.forEach(doc => {                    
                    let colab = doc.data()

                      this.colaborador.push(colab)

                      let colR = this.colaborador.find(colR => colR.uidCol == auth.currentUser.uid)

                        if (colR.SistemaApp == "Restaurante") {

                            this.colRestaurante.push(colR)
                        }
          }
    ...
}
```

So, i Can get de array **colaborador** but i can Not get the Object **colRestaurante**.

in my html:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ colaborador }}</div> //RESULT [{ "username": carlos, "SistemaApp": Restaurante }]
  <div>{{colRestaurante}}</div> // RESULT ... NOTHING
</template>
```

What am i missing?. I am expectting to get this:

{ "username": carlos, "SistemaApp": Restaurante }

can any help me please?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U defined `colRestaurante` as String type, and in your code u are doing such thing:

```
this.colRestaurante.push(colR)
```

U can not push smth to string.

After that try to debug this code:

```
colR.SistemaApp == "Restaurante"
```

Maybe this `colR.SistemaApp` could never be equal to `"Restaurante"`. And use `===` instead of `==`